# Converting a 2d array to polygon points

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, polygon, tile

Suppose you have a 2d array like the ones often used to organise tile maps, 1 represents solid tiles.

```
var map = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
];
```

Instead of square tiles, I want to convert this shape in to points of a polygon. Each 1 in the array would have a set width and height like a tile map, but I only want the corner points necessary to recreate the shape as a solid polygon. I also want diagonal slopes instead of a step-like effect when the 1's are diagonal like in the array. I've played around and searched for an answer but I can't figure out the best way to do this, any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: google `marching squares`

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script defer="defer">
      var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 578,
        height: 200
      });

      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

      var poly = new Kinetic.Line({
        points: [73, 192, 73, 160, 340, 23, 500, 109, 499, 139, 342, 93],
        fill: '#00D2FF',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 5,
        closed: true
      });

      // add the shape to the layer
      layer.add(poly);

      // add the layer to the stage
      stage.add(layer);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You could put those points you want in the points array ,and use kinetic js for ur project.

Link : http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-polygon-tutorial/

Comment: I need the minimum number of points stored for collision detection and calculating line of sight as well as rendering though, so I'm just after an algorithm to figure that out when the map is loaded.

Comment: @MrAdam try Douglas-Peucker algorithm.